# Using Selenium in Python to select a radio button

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a bot that automates booking a study room (Microsoft booking). When I try to select the radio button, it doesn't work. I tried using id and CSS_SELECTOR. I appreciate any help you can provide.

[I want select room C, ID:service_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jML2r.png)

```
room_c_select=driver.find_element(By.ID, "service_2")
room_c_select.click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#service_2").click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='right serviceCard']input[type='radio'][id='service_2']")[0].click()
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" do you get an error or something?

Comment: No error it just doesn't select it

Comment: ok, do you have to click on the small circle or on any point of the card?

Comment: You can click on any point in the card and it still works... I am talking about manually....

Comment: ok, well it's hard to tell what's going on without having access to the site, could you share it? or the full html code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19QaSrL5MFFBGh1YaZ1KO6pV7ULT6m9EL/view?usp=share_link        you should be able to find the HTML code here. u can't open the website without my uni email and log-in info :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click on the small circle, i.e.

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.image.icon-circleRegular')[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find_elements()` to locate any specific element isn't a part of the best practices as demonstrated by the other answer.

As per the [html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19QaSrL5MFFBGh1YaZ1KO6pV7ULT6m9EL/view) published as a comment, to click on the [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) associated with the text **Group Study Room C** you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='name line-clamp' and text()='Group Study Room C']//ancestor::label[1]").click()
```

Comment: Isn't `//div[text()='Group Study Room C']//ancestor::label` enough?

Comment: @soundwave Apparently enough. But as per the best practices an index is required which can make a difference in rarest of the rare usecases.